# Redirecting form to current browser url (ATG)

Tags: redirect, form-submit, atg

I have a form which is included on all the pages of our website. The dsp:form action attribute is same as the current page url. This works fine for most of our pages but fails when a user submits the form on a page where browser shows a seo friendly url.

For example when a user submits the form on one of our product pages www.mysite.com/products/prdName the page refreshes and redirects user to www.mysite.com/prodSpec/index.jsp

How can i keep user on the same browser url on form sumission?

TIA

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Comment: Which form handler are you using? If you are using a custom form handler, please let me know, and I could perhaps provide a concrete answer. Please see this section in the documentation if you are using a standard form handler; it should help: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41069_01/Platform.11-0/ATGPageDevGuide/html/s0805redirectingonformsubmission01.html

Comment: Hi Matt,We are using a custom form handler.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are using to map SEO-friendly URLs? Are you doing URL rewriting in your web server? Using a third party ATG framework? or using ATG's own?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using therein property value `/OriginatingRequest.requestURI` as your `successUrl` value?

`OriginatingRequest` is a request-scoped component that represents the current HTTP request (specifically, the instance of `DynamoHTTPRequest`)

Comment: Thanks Vihung. I found an alternative solution to my issue but will try what you suggested as well.

Comment: @user3465554 I face the same issue. I cannot get the full url with OriginatingRequest.requestURI. How did you resolve your problem?Please help me.

Comment: @Vihung any idea?